# error parsing XML: unbound prefix in schooltraq

Tags: android, xml

I searched and found some really eat my similar questions here, but I tried the resolutions that appeared but nothing solved my problem.

And i have the error unbound prefix in this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ProgressWheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.visualdenim.schooltraq"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <com.example.progressbar.ProgressWheel
            android:id="@+id/progressBarTwo"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            ProgressWheel:text="Click\none of the\nbuttons"
            ProgressWheel:textColor="#222222"
            ProgressWheel:textSize="14sp"
            ProgressWheel:rimColor="#44000000"
            ProgressWheel:barLength="60dp" 
            ProgressWheel:barColor="#339BB9"
            ProgressWheel:barWidth="25dp"
            ProgressWheel:rimWidth="25dp" 
            ProgressWheel:spinSpeed="3dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <com.example.progressbar.ProgressWheel
            android:id="@+id/progressBarThree"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            ProgressWheel:text=""
            ProgressWheel:textColor="#222222"
            ProgressWheel:textSize="14sp"
            ProgressWheel:rimColor="#44000000"
            ProgressWheel:circleColor="#2E9121"
            ProgressWheel:barLength="20dp" 
            ProgressWheel:barColor="#8000"
            ProgressWheel:barWidth="25dp"
            ProgressWheel:rimWidth="25dp" 
            ProgressWheel:spinSpeed="-1dp" />

        <com.example.progressbar.ProgressWheel
            android:id="@+id/progressBarFour"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            ProgressWheel:text=""
            ProgressWheel:textColor="#222222"
            ProgressWheel:textSize="14sp"
            ProgressWheel:rimColor="#4000"
            ProgressWheel:barLength="30dp" 
            ProgressWheel:barColor="#222"
            ProgressWheel:barWidth="4dp"
            ProgressWheel:rimWidth="1dp" 
            ProgressWheel:spinSpeed="30dp"
            ProgressWheel:delayMillis="75" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your package name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ProgressWheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.progressbar" // changed
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >

        <com.example.progressbar.ProgressWheel
            android:id="@+id/progressBarTwo"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            ProgressWheel:text="Click\none of the\nbuttons"
            ProgressWheel:textColor="#222222"
            ProgressWheel:textSize="14sp"
            ProgressWheel:rimColor="#44000000"
            ProgressWheel:barLength="60dp" 
            ProgressWheel:barColor="#339BB9"
            ProgressWheel:barWidth="25dp"
            ProgressWheel:rimWidth="25dp" 
            ProgressWheel:spinSpeed="3dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <com.example.progressbar.ProgressWheel
            android:id="@+id/progressBarThree"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            ProgressWheel:text=""
            ProgressWheel:textColor="#222222"
            ProgressWheel:textSize="14sp"
            ProgressWheel:rimColor="#44000000"
            ProgressWheel:circleColor="#2E9121"
            ProgressWheel:barLength="20dp" 
            ProgressWheel:barColor="#8000"
            ProgressWheel:barWidth="25dp"
            ProgressWheel:rimWidth="25dp" 
            ProgressWheel:spinSpeed="-1dp" />

        <com.example.progressbar.ProgressWheel
            android:id="@+id/progressBarFour"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            ProgressWheel:text=""
            ProgressWheel:textColor="#222222"
            ProgressWheel:textSize="14sp"
            ProgressWheel:rimColor="#4000"
            ProgressWheel:barLength="30dp" 
            ProgressWheel:barColor="#222"
            ProgressWheel:barWidth="4dp"
            ProgressWheel:rimWidth="1dp" 
            ProgressWheel:spinSpeed="30dp"
            ProgressWheel:delayMillis="75" />

</RelativeLayout>
```